# Dynamic page with json data - page template

Tags: html, ajax, json, database

my situation is this. 
I need to create a site structure like this: `HOME` + `SINGLE PAGE TEMPLATE` like `member.html` 
Think about a team, with people. When click on one of them, I display the `SINGLE PAGE OF THE PERSON`, so `member.html` with specific data took from `JSON`. For example, if I click on John the personal page of John appears, with the structure of `member.html` . 
My idea is to call with Ajax the `PAGE TEMPLATE - member.html` and fill it with the data from `JSON` ( in this case the John datas). Everything is fine, I can do that. 
But now I have a problem. 
Is there a way to have that single page directly reachable? Like `www.test.com/JohnDoe`

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could examine the url when the page loads. You can access the current url using

```
window.location.href
```

Then once you have this you just need to do some simple string parsing to work out which ajax call to make and what to display.

Comment: I don't think it works, how can I analyze the page it the page doesn't exist? The member page is something like `member.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing a simple RESTful/CRUD website, you would probably encode this as as part of the URL. So your AJAX call would be made to `www.test.com/users/:id`, with the `:id` part being the id of the user that was clicked on, in your database.

Where you are handling the request on the server side, you could then detect whether the request is an ajax call or not and serve either a JSON or an HTML response.

Comment: I give you more info in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP : everytime the template is executed (or shown) with data, you create a folder with the member's name and create a file named "index.html" inside this folder with the member's data.

Next are two PHP files, the first one, **create_subdir.php**, let the user to choose a member (John Doe with ID=106 is hardcoded), then it calls **member.php**, that is suppose to load the template and show the data on screen (you do this part: connect to database, select data, display it), but it does something else: it creates a folder with the member's name and creates a file inside this folder with the name "index.html", filled with member's data. Here they are :

**create_subdir.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="member.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="id" value="106" hidden/> <!-- JOHN DOE'S ID -->
      <input type="submit" value="Click to see John Doe's data" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**member.php**

```
<?php

$id = $_POST["id"]; // GET MEMBER'S ID.
$name = "John Doe"; // DATA RETRIEVED FROM DATABASE WITH "ID".
// CREATE FOLDER WITH MEMBER'S NAME.
  $flag = mkdir( $name );
// CREATE FILE.
  $flag = file_put_contents( $name . "/" . "index.html","Data to fill file" );

echo "Page created = " . $flag;  // JUST TO CHECK IF EVERYTHING WENT FINE.
// header( "Location: create_subdir.php" );  // RETURN TO PREVIOUS PAGE.
?>
```

The advantage of this approach, is that, everytime the template is executed for a member, his page will be automatically updated because the file "index.html" inside his own folder will be re-created.